# Notepad ++ User language

Tags: notepad++

I want to create a user language to remind me of SML. I wish to make it to remind me of emacs.

The question is, is it possible to make a color of a arbitrary name after a keyword? If I have

```
fun average (x, y) = (x + y) div 2;
```

Then fun would be purple, but the name average can also be called avg or something third. Is it possible to make it a color, red or blue. Or

```
val fadeRed = I.recolour (colourAverage( 255, 0, 0));
```

Then val would be yellowish and fadeRed which could also be called fRed or something third should be reddish.

Is it possible to set this up in notepad++ when u create a user language?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in N++.
In **SynWrite** editor it's possible:

- create new lexer (copy Text Files to new name)
- add 2 styles: red and purple
- add 2 parsers: 1) which finds word at linestart: regex `^\w+` and 2) which finds word which is after a line-start and first word (such regex can be written, easy).

See Readme folder for lexer-tutor.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly... yes you can do this...
Follow the steps:

1. Go to **Language** --> **Define your language**
2. Click on **Create New** and give it a name of your choice say **My Custom**
3. Now write similar keywords which you want of same style in **1st Group**... e.g. **fun** in your current case, select **Style** and choose color, font etc of your choice for this group.
4. Select another group and set of possible words e.g. "average avg" or all possible words without any delimiter. Just separate with one space.
5. Define other group in similar way.
6. Close this user defined language window.
7. Write your texts say "fun average (x, y) = (x + y) div 2;" in any new document
8. Select Language from menu and select "**My Custom**" from there

In fact you can also set the desired extension which automatically open in this formatting... e.g. if ext is say **.SaN**, then the file having same extension e.g. **test.SaN** will automatically will get opened in this formatting.

[image: Custom_Formatting_NPP]